# RemoteError: Remote error: NoMoreNetworks

Tags: cloud-computing, openstack, nova-network

I get this error when I try to start the machine. There are free IP addresses (both floating and fixed). I tried to look about it on the web, but no luck (there is an answer somewhere which doesnt solve my problem).

Here the entire traceback: http://pastebin.com/vB0gm1GH

Thank you.

Comment: LE: I discovered that one of the project works (my main project). That project spawns instances without a problem.

Comment: Seems like it can't find any (suitable) network in the database, have you checked   how the networks are stored within the SQL database?  Maybe you can find out what query is executed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it after all. The problem is that every project needs it's own fixed network (that's why my main project was working, because i added the network during the installation).